# How do i set a value as a list for a particular key in redis?

Tags: node.js, list, redis, key-value

I had to check if i can put expire on a list which is value to a key. for this i can do the following.

```
rpush mylist 1 2 3
> prints 1 2 3
set key mylist
> prints "ok"
expire key 5
>prints "(integer) 1"
```

this would only expire the connection between key and mylist

```
get key
>prints (nil)
```

would result in a null. but the list (mylist here) exists

```
lrange mylist 0 -1
> prints "1 2 3"
```

prints all values in the list. i want the list to be destroyed. how do i do it in commandline or nodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of the key "key" to the string "mylist". You aren't creating a reference between "key" and the list mylist.

- `EXPIRE MYLIST 5` will expire the key mylist containing the List object - https://redis.io/topics/data-types
- `SET KEY MYLIST` sets a key with a *string* value of "mylist".

Thus, calling `EXPIRE` on the mylist key has no relation to calling `EXPIRE` on the key called "key".

Answer (score 0):

you can `expire mylist 5` so that your list will get expire along with the key as well

Comment: it would do nothing to the key-value pair.
still when being called
"get key"
would result "mylist"

Comment: You need to expire both